# Testing services along with controller and API routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jasmine, karma-runner

I currently use [jasmine](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine) with [karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html) to unit test my Angular controllers. I use JSON fixtures with mock data rather than relying on my actual services to make API calls.

Separately I test my API endpoints using [jasmine-node](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node).

My question is, do I need to also test my services in order to have a solid test suite? I feel like it would be overkill as all that is in my services are very simple `$resource` `GET` methods, and testing `$resource` is obviously not something which is necessary.

Comment: testing with mock data is fine but with the actual service is a good practice.